# If there exist infinitely many non negative terms in a sequence, can we say that $\lim \sup \geq 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If there exist infinitely many non negative terms in a sequence, can we say that $\lim \sup \geq 0 $?

Actually I'm trying to understand a proof of "$\lim \sup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}\ n]{|a_n|} < 1 $ Then the series $ \sum |a_n|$ convegres" and in the proof it is written that $\lim \sup \geq 0$.
So naturally, this question arises.

Comment: Yes, you can. Can you prove it?

Comment: we can take a subsequence say $(x_{nk})$containing only non-negative terms then its $ \lim \sup (x_{nk}) \geq 0$ and $ \lim \sup(x_n) \geq \lim \sup (x_{nk}) \geq 0$.  will this work?